# How to access individual strings in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, string

I am trying to access two strings which are coupled together. I do not know how to access them individually, as subscription does not work.

I tried printing the variable b in the following example, and I get two strings. However using b[0] does not give me the first string separately.

```
import numpy as np
import json
import requests
from datetime import datetime

resp = requests.get("https://api.mfapi.in/mf/130503")
data = resp.json()

x = data['data']

for i in range(1):
    for a,b in x[i].items():
        print(b)
```

Comment: can you show your expected output?

Comment: you got two strings because the inner for loop ran for 2 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because in your loop `i` starts and stops at `1`. You can access the first one trough `x[0]['date']` and `x[0]['nav']`

Comment: Data seems to be a list of dictionaries so you can easily obtain the keys or values.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `x` is a list of dictionaries

Depending on if you want to access `date` or `nav` in the dictionaries, in your for loop you can just use `x[i]['date']` or `x[i]['nav']`